# Global instance of class in Robotframework

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a problem working with the robotframework and since its kind of hard to debug I have trouble to find the core of the problem.
Following, I will try to explain my issue with as much detail as possible:

So, imagine I have a power supply sitting on my desk, which I want to call by an API. I have the API imported into a python file - lets call it PowerSupply.py - which consists of a class with the same name as the file. The code in the file is simplified for presentation purposes.

```
#PowerSupply.py

import powersupplyapi

class PowerSupply():
   def __init__(self):
      self.connect = None
   
   def connect(self):
      self.connect = powersupplyapi.connect()

   def set_voltage(self, voltage):
      self.voltage = powersupplyapi.set_voltage(voltage)

   def set_current(self, current):
      self.current = powersupplyapi.set_current(current)
```

Now, I want to use the class methods as keywords in the robotframework. Imagine the folder structure like this:

```
| --source
    | --PowerSupply.py
| --tests
    | --__init__.robot
    | --01_test.robot
    | --02_test.robot
    | --resources/
        | --Resource.resource
```

In the resource file I imported the library.

```
#Resource.resource

*** Settings ***
Library   ../source/PowerSupply.py
```

In the __init__.robot file I imported the resource file.

```
#__init__.robot
*** Settings ***
Resource ./resources/Resource.resource
```

Now, what I want to do is to instantiate the class which was imported for the library once (preferably in the __init__.robot file) and then use the keywords in 01_test and 02_test. The issue right now is that the tests apparently wont access the same instance of the class so in return the keywords wont work.

What I so far tried was to use the Suite Setup/Teardown in the __init__.robot file but sadly that didnt work because the tests did not get passed the same instance of the class.

In another Tutorial I saw the possibility to set the class as a global variable and then pass it to the tests.

```
*** Variables ***
${POWERSUPPLY_INSTANCE}=   Set Variable PowerSupply()
```

Sadly that did also not work for me because the 'Set Variable' Keyword only seems to work when used in a test case.

What am I missing here? Does anyone with more experience have a recommendation for what to try next? Does this even work the way I want it to?

Im glad for any kind of help and want to send my thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the `connect` attribute? Is it meant to be a variable or a method?

Comment: In this context its an attribute. Since I have simplified the code I kind of did a mistake there. In reality the device which is to be connect returns a flag from connect() method which signalises if the connection via USB was succesful or not. For the issue im trying to solve it shouldnt really make a difference as far as im aware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to do is to define [library scope](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#library-scope). By default robotframework creates new instance for each test case. To change it you should add to class definition `ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = "GLOBAL"`. Also it would be good to call connect method (from robotframework perspective it's keyword) somewhere in suite setup in order to avoid dependency on some particular test.

Also one more thing. You in your example you are naming files as `x_test.robot`, but these files are actually suites which could have own suite setup and teardown. If you want to have one suite setup and teardown for all files you should turn directory in yet another suite by adding `__init__.robot` and defining suite setup and teardown there. Info about suite initialization file could be found [here](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#suite-initialization-files).

Comment: Setting the Library Scope to global made it work. Thank you very much!